# I am unable to upload an image to the backend using http and image picker for flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-http

*Here  is my function for uploading to the server using http . I have tried to convert the image to a base64 string but still the issue persists*

```
uploadImage() async {

var postUri = Uri.parse('${xyz}/api/v1/listing/store');
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);
request.fields['name'] = titleTEC.text.toString();
request.fields['category_id'] = selectedCategoryId.toString();
request.fields['price'] = priceTEC.text.toString();
request.fields['discount'] = 2.toString();
request.fields['discount_type'] = 'percent';
request.headers['moduleId'] = 2.toString();
Uint8List _list = await singleImage.readAsBytes();
request.files.add(http.MultipartFile(
  'image', singleImage.readAsBytes().asStream(), _list.length,
  filename: '${DateTime.now().toString()}.png',
));

// request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromString('image', base64Image));

request.send().then((response) {

  print(response.statusCode);
});
```

}

[image: This is the error i get when I hit the functions p.s. I am specifically using flutter web]

Comment: How do you get the image?

Comment: `Future pickImage() async {
    XFile pickedImage = await singlePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 10);
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      // singleImage = File(pickedImage.path);
      singleImage = pickedImage;
      bodies.add(MultipartBody('image',singleImage));


      setState(() {




      });
    } else {
      print('no image selected');
    }
  }`
was using this function to get the image. I fugured it out. Just had to pass 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', in headers and little bit tweaking for uploading images

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, it works perfectly

```
Future<String> uploadImage(String username,String password,File? image,String desc) async {

Map<String,String> body = {
  "username"          : username,
  "password"          : password,
  "desc"              : desc,
};

var response = http.MultipartRequest(
  "POST",
  Uri.parse("$dataURL/prescription"),
);
final httpImage = http.MultipartFile("image" , image!.readAsBytes().asStream(),image.lengthSync(),filename: image.path);

response.headers.addAll({'Content-type' : 'application/json' , 'Accept' : 'application/json'});
response.fields.addAll(body);
response.files.add(httpImage);

http.StreamResponse result = await response.send();

print("checkedUpload: ${result.statusCode}");

return await result.stream.bytesToString();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stack trace, it seems that you're calling into `dart:io` code, that is NOT supported on the web. Are you sure the `sixam_mart` code is designed to work in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

use dio package, it is also used for api calls and its so effective.

```
  Future updateProfilePicApi(File profilepic) async {
    dynamic responseJson;
    try {
      var dio = Dio();
     
      String fileName = profilepic.path.split('/').last;
      FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
        
        "image":
            await MultipartFile.fromFile(profilepic.path, filename: fileName),
      });

      var response = await dio.post('${xyz}/api/v1/listing/store',
          options: Options(
              headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                
              },
              followRedirects: false,
              validateStatus: (status) {
                return status! <= 500;
              }),
          data: formData);
      print("::::::::::::::::status code::::::::::::::");
      print(response.statusCode);
      responseJson = response.data;
    } on SocketException {
      print("no internet");
    }
    return responseJson;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the image file using path

request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', filepath));

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).